# if image exists show image else show different image

Tags: php

I have this code in my php file.

```
<div class="the-avatar">
<div class="flash"></div>
<div class="avatar">
<img src="avatar/default-avatar.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I want to do this:
if file upload/user_avatar.jpg exist 
show upload/user_avatar.jpg 
 else 
show avatar/default-avatar.jpg

Comment: This question shows ZERO research effort. Have you looked at the php docs? Did you do any research before posting this question?

Comment: You should search it into Google first

Comment: You've also only posted HTML content... Where is the PHP involved?

Answer (score 0):

Save it to a dB if you ask me, checking everytime seems awkward.

Anyways,

```
$filename = 'upload/user_avatar.jpg';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
  echo '<img src="'. $filename .'" alt="" />';
} else {
  echo '<img src="avatar/default-avatar.jpg" alt="" />';
}
```

Straight from https://www.php.net/file_exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php
    if (file_exists('upload/user_avatar.jpg')) {
        echo "<img src='upload/user_avatar.jpg'>";
    } else {
        echo "<img src='avatar/default-avatar.jpg'>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution.

```
<div class="the-avatar">
<div class="flash"></div>
<div class="avatar">
<img src="<?php 
If (file_exists('upload/user_avatar.jpg')) {
echo 'upload/user_avatar.jpg';
} else {
echo 'upload/default_avatar.jpg';
}
?>" alt="">
</div>
```